# Display Oracle Abstract Data Types(ADT) in PHP (Yii2)

Tags: php, oracle, yii2

I need to use Abstract Data Types (Object, VARRAY) in my app.
I managed to implement it in my views, but when I try get db data in PHP (Yii2) I got errors like:

`oci_fetch_all(): ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got ADT
inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got ADT`

`ORA-22950: cannot ORDER objects without MAP or ORDER method`

Is there any way to get data stored as ADT (Object, VARRAY, ..) in PHP?

**Update:**

I get data from database with query:

```
$result = (new Query)
    ->select('p.*')->from('MY_VIEW p')->all();
```

My SQL file contains:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_object AS OBJECT (
    fiedl1 VARCHAR2(255),
    fiedl2 VARCHAR2(255)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function
    RETURN my_object 
    IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN(my_object(FIELD1','FIELD2'));
    END;



create or replace view MY_VIEW as
    SELECT *, my_function() as adt_field FROM ...
```

Comment: Share the query that you are using to fetch and sort the data

Comment: @Tejash I updated my post